# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una variable int a una const char?

Tags: c++, arduino

Ok, soy un estudiante de electrónica que está tratando de controlar 6 servomotores usando Arduino y el módulo RF 433MHz. En el código, estoy usando la librería RadioHead para hacer uso de este módulo. Sin embargo, al controlar los servomotores con encoders rotativos, estos generan una señal que en el código para Arduino se interpretan como una variable int, pero para enviarlas por el módulo RF con modulación ASK se deben enviar como una variable de tipo const char y no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer eso.
Adjunto el código para que me entiendan mejor:
(También acepto recomendaciones para optimizar el código)

```
//PROGRAMA EMISOR//
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RH_ASK rf_driver;
int PosPrevia1=90;
volatile int Posicion1;
const char *Pos1=90;
int PosPrevia2=90;
volatile int Posicion2;
const char *Pos2=90;
int PosPrevia3=90;
volatile int Posicion3=90;
const char *Pos3=90;
int PosPrevia4=90;
volatile int Posicion4;
const char *Pos4=90;
int PosPrevia5=90;
volatile int Posicion5;
const char *Pos5=90;
int PosPrevia6=90;
volatile int Posicion6; 
const char *Pos6=90;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
    
  rf_driver.init();
  
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(1, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(0), encoder1, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), encoder2, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(4), encoder3, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(6), encoder4, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(8), encoder5, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(10), encoder6, LOW);

}

void loop() {
    while(Serial.available()>0){
    if(Posicion1!=PosPrevia1){
    PosPrevia1=Posicion1;
    *Pos1=Posicion1;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos1, strlen(Pos1);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
    if(Posicion2!=PosPrevia2){
    PosPrevia2=Posicion2;
    *Pos2=Posicion2;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos2, strlen(Pos2);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
     if(Posicion3!=PosPrevia3){
    PosPrevia3=Posicion3;
    *Pos3=Posicion3;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos2, strlen(Pos2);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
    if(Posicion4!=PosPrevia4){
    PosPrevia4=Posicion4;
    *Pos4=Posicion4;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos4, strlen(Pos4);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
    if(Posicion5!=PosPrevia5){
    PosPrevia5=Posicion5;
    *Pos5=Posicion5;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos5, strlen(Pos5);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
    if(Posicion6!=PosPrevia6){
    PosPrevia6=Posicion6;
    *Pos6=Posicion6;
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)Pos6, strlen(Pos6);
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    }
    }
    delay(200);

}


void encoder1(){
  static unsigned long ultInter1=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter1= millis();
  if(tiempoInter1-ultInter1>5){
    if(digitalRead(1)==HIGH){
      Posicion1++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion1-- ;
      }
      Posicion1=min(180,max(0,Posicion1));
      ultInter1=tiempoInter1;  
    }
  }
  void encoder2(){
  static unsigned long ultInter2=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter2= millis();
  if(tiempoInter2-ultInter2>5){
    if(digitalRead(3)==HIGH){
      Posicion2++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion2-- ;
      }
      Posicion2=min(180,max(0,Posicion2));
      ultInter2=tiempoInter2;  
    }
  }
  void encoder3(){
  static unsigned long ultInter3=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter3= millis();
  if(tiempoInter3-ultInter3>5){
    if(digitalRead(5)==HIGH){
      Posicion3++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion3-- ;
      }
      Posicion3=min(180,max(0,Posicion3));
      ultInter3=tiempoInter3;  
    }
  }
  void encoder4(){
  static unsigned long ultInter4=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter4= millis();
  if(tiempoInter4-ultInter4>5){
    if(digitalRead(7)==HIGH){
      Posicion4++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion4-- ;
      }
      Posicion4=min(180,max(0,Posicion4));
      ultInter4=tiempoInter4;  
    }
  }
  void encoder5(){
  static unsigned long ultInter5=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter5= millis();
  if(tiempoInter5-ultInter5>5){
    if(digitalRead(9)==HIGH){
      Posicion5++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion5-- ;
      }
      Posicion5=min(180,max(0,Posicion5));
      ultInter5=tiempoInter5;  
    }
  }
  void encoder6(){
  static unsigned long ultInter6=0;
  unsigned long tiempoInter6= millis();
  if(tiempoInter6-ultInter6>5){
    if(digitalRead(11)==HIGH){
      Posicion6++ ;
      }
      else{
        Posicion6-- ;
      }
      Posicion6=min(180,max(0,Posicion6));
      ultInter6=tiempoInter6;  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

El calificador `const` es una característica del tipo que le dice al compilador "*Yo, como programador, me comprometo a no modificar estos datos*"<sup>1</sup>, respecto a pasar de entero (`int`) a carácter (`char`) se puede hacer una conversión implícita:

```
int cinco_i = 5;
const char cinco_c = i; // Convierte int a char
```

Una conversión que pasa de un tipo de mayor tamaño (`int` suele ser de 4 bytes) a uno de menor tamaño (`char` suele ser de un byte) se conoce como *estrechamiento* (en inglés *narrowing*) y puede provodar pérdida de datos.

Pero muy probablemente tú no estás buscando este tipo de conversión, deduzco por tu enunciado (que no por tu código) que pretendes [serializar datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n):

> pero para enviarlas por el módulo RF con modulación ASK se deben enviar como una variable de tipo const char

La serialización no se suele hacer sobre datos de tipo `char` ya que éste es un dato con signo y puede provocar desbordamientos<sup>2</sup> de datos que cambien el valor serializado, para serializar se suele usar un dato de tipo `unsigned char` y necesitarás tantos de ellos como largo sea el dato que quieres serializar:

```
// Asumiendo sizeof(unsigned char) == 1
int valor = 0xcafecafe;
const auto longitud = sizeof(valor);
unsigned char dato[longitud] {};
// Reinterpreta 'valor' como un puntero a 'unsigned char' y 
// copia 'longitud' valores de el valor reinterpretado
// al búfer 'longitud'.
std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&valor), longitud, dato);
```

Podemos comprobar que la serialización ha funcionado:

```
for (const int valor : dato)
    std::cout << std::hex << valor << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLTsMwEDzHX7ESEklQoeXaJpX4Ba6AKmNvUkuON/IDtVT9Ma58WHCclrYHS@udnZmdFX3/KDQ37TDcKSN0kAiVIuct8m7NLj2uW7LKb2OTKeOh48oUJTuwbD6HFxc6hUYSOPWN1BTBONUalCC23JZQ1/DMspH2xTVZqGGxE7zB8a1YJsg4Dzx4Ak2mVT7IOHKSSowyTt1oguSe3s7TH3A4rtImrxhd0PYWPYc8cXMQ1BEEA30YMYKI3IjlsIfEFtSrCJ5l82lddBAvgPq0vL2ykJR4XMPn70@D9or7xDLn5XIZNfcbU1yxNoI7X93GeVgX91PS2f8NZilkjM6yJvoW05kuV1xOOMvORsFDVUH6bHE31tNgLPJ3k49C0T5YA4sVOw7DHw)</kbd>. Una vez serializado el dato en un búfer de `unsigned char`, puedes pasar este búfer a la función que sea que espera `const` (probablemente `unsigned`) `char`:

```
void f(unsigned char *);

f(dato);
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Hay maneras oscuras y enrevesadas que permiten modificar un dato `const`, pero programando sin hacer nada excepcional el propio compilador prohibirá modificar esos datos.

###### <sup>2</sup>Un tipo de 8 bits puede almacenar 2<sup>8</sup> valores, si es con signo (aproximadamente) la mitad de estos valores serán positivos y la otra negativos; en otras palabras: no se puede almacenar (por ejemplo) el valor `200` en una variable `char` y éste valor se transformaría en otro.